# Is there a RSS Feed web part for a SharePoint modern page - Communications site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, communication-site, rss

Is there a RSS web part for SharePoint online - comms site?

If there is none, is there any way I can display RSS feed on a comms site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an SharePoint default RSS feed web part to a Communication Site.

**Workaround**:

Use this SPFx web part (RSS Reader) created by community members: [RSS Reader](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-rss-reader)

Comment: Just saw that too. Thanks